# Can I ask questions about MediaWiki here?

Tags: discussion, suitable-question

[Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237154/where-should-i-direct-questions-about-wikia#237154) a link from a question about this on the Meta site for Stack Exchange.

Basically I want some help with the syntax of MediaWiki, like how can I create templates like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_drug).

Specifics: as commentators requested. I am interested in creating these templates to be fully functional so that I can utilize them in articles. Like I'd love to be able to create *drugboxes* for my articles on this Wiki.

Now, I realize this is generalized, but all I want is someone to give me an explanation, and then walk me through it.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, it depends on your specific question however. We do have questions on MediaWiki templates [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=MediaWiki+templates+is%3Aquestion).

If the question is simply `how can I create templates like this` however, then that would be considered too broad to answer in under a few paragraphs, so would be off-topic here. Also, if it involves extensive programming, then it would likely be a better fit for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) where there are more programmers to help.

In regards to the "Specifics" added to your question, without seeing the actual question, I can only further state that according to our guidelines on [What topics can I ask about here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): `Questions about other CMSs [exluding  WordPress, Drupal, Magento, Tridion, or Salesforce] may be asked here on Pro Webmasters.`

So the subject area is on-topic, and really depends on *how* you ask your question(s). You can read more about how to ask questions by reviewing the `Asking` section in our [Help Center](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help).